# How to apply a 3x3 filter with a convolutional layer correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

Im trying to apply a simple laplacian filter (3x3) to an image, but get a very noisy output

```
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL.Image as pil
import numpy as np

k = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1],[1, -8, 1],[1, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)

image = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 1])

kernel = tf.reshape(k, [3, 3, 1, 1], name='kernel')

res = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv2d(image, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME"))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    img = pil.open('grey.png')
    array = np.asarray(img).reshape(1, img.size[0], img.size[1], 1)

    out = sess.run(res, feed_dict={image:array})
    reverted = ((pil.fromarray(np.uint8(out))).convert('L')).save('testing.png')
```

[image: Noisy outputimage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convolution is applied correctly. The problem is with the image back conversion. Namely, you're applying a filter with some negative values, the ***-8*** in the middle. This means that a lot of convolved pixels will have a negative resulting value, which then you cast to `np.uint8` when done. Therefore a ***-1*** will become ***255*** and thus ***1*** and ***-1*** will have vastly different light values associated with them. This causes the pattern.

Change the following two lines:

```
array = np.asarray(img, dtype = np.float32 ).reshape(1, img.size[0], img.size[1], 1) / 2
```

and

```
reverted = ((pil.fromarray(np.uint8(out + 128))).convert('L')).save('testing.png')
```

and you will get an image that makes sense. Of course you might come up with much better ideas how to handle negative values, casting the original pixels to ***[0, 127.5]*** and then adding ***128*** to the result is a quick and dirty solution, but it solves the problem. You really need to think about this, because you can also get overflows if the middle pixel is zero and the others have significant values.

Using the changed code, a random Angelina Jolie image results in:

[image: Angelina Jolie Laplacian filtered]